# Output from final chunk appears at top of output

Tags: r, r-markdown, quarto

In a quarto document, I would like the final R chunk to compute an executive summary based on the results of earlier chunks. How can this final chunk output appear at the top of the report?

Expected Output: final chunk (exec-summary) output should appear under 'Executive Summary' and before 'Number of Rows':

````
---
title: "exec-summary"
format: html
---

## Executive Summary Presentation

### Number of Rows

```{r chunk1}
x <- nrow(mtcars)
```

### Number of Columns

```{r chunk2}
y <- ncol(mtcars)
```

### Executive Summary Computation

```{r exec-summary}
glue::glue("There are {x} rows an {y} columns")
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either make use of Lua filter to reposition the chunk output that will work across formats (i.e. for pdf, html, docx etc) or can use javascript which will work only for html output format. I am showing both of the approaches below.

For both of the cases, create a placeholder empty pandoc div with `:::` and use an id (which will be used by lua or js code) and wrap the `exec-summary` code chunk with another div with an id (again which will be used by lua or js code to get the output content).

### Using Lua Filter (Robust approach)

````
---
title: "exec-summary"
format: html
filters: 
  - move-output.lua
---

## Executive Summary Presentation

::: {#placeholder}
:::

### Number of Rows

```{r chunk1}
x <- nrow(mtcars)
```

### Number of Columns

```{r chunk2}
y <- ncol(mtcars)
```

### Executive Summary Computation

::: {#exec-summary}

```{r exec-summary}
glue::glue("There are {x} rows an {y} columns")
```

:::
````

**move-output.lua**

```lua
local exec_summary_output = nil

function get_exec_summary_output()
  return {
    Div = function(el)
      if el.classes:includes("cell-output") then
        exec_summary_output = el.content
        el.content = ""
        return el
      end
    end
  }
end

function get_exec_summary() 
  return {
    Div = function(el)
      if el.identifier == "exec-summary" then
        local elm = el:walk(get_exec_summary_output())
        return elm
      end
      return el
    end
  }
end

function replace_placeholder(content)
  return {
    Div = function(el)
      if el.identifier == "placeholder" then
        el.content = content
      end
      return el
    end
  }
end

function Pandoc(doc)
  local doc = doc:walk(get_exec_summary())
  return doc:walk(replace_placeholder(exec_summary_output))
end
```

### Using Javascript

````
---
title: "exec-summary"
format: 
  html:
    include-in-header: move-output.html
---

## Executive Summary Presentation

::: {#placeholder}
:::

### Number of Rows

```{r chunk1}
x <- nrow(mtcars)
```

### Number of Columns

```{r chunk2}
y <- ncol(mtcars)
```

### Executive Summary Computation

::: {#exec-summary}

```{r exec-summary}
glue::glue("There are {x} rows an {y} columns")
```

:::
````

**move-output.html**

```html
<script>
  function move_exec_summary() {
    let exec_summary = document.querySelector('div#exec-summary div.cell-output');
    let placeholder = document.querySelector('div#placeholder');
    placeholder.insertBefore(exec_summary, placeholder.firstChild);
  }

  window.document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
    move_exec_summary();
  });
</script>
```

---

[image: rendered output for both of the above cases]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get exactly what you want *immediately* after the level 2 header (because neither `x` nor `y` exist at that point), but you can do this:

````
---
title: "exec-summary"
format: html
---

## Executive Summary Presentation

```{r dynamic-summary, results='asis', echo=FALSE}
cat(
  paste0(
    "\n\n### Executive Summary Computation\n\n", 
    glue::glue("There are {nrow(mtcars)} rows and {ncol(mtcars)} columns")
  )
)
```

### Number of Rows

```{r chunk1}
x <- nrow(mtcars)
```

### Number of Columns

```{r chunk2}
y <- ncol(mtcars)
```
````

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Although this works for the small example I posted, I'm looking for a solution that allows a result that appears at the top of the output file to be computed at the bottom of the rmarkdown/quarto file.

Comment: In that case @shafee's solution is undoubtedly better.